# Ctest from within adb shell

Tags: android, cmake, adb, googletest, ctest

How do I run ctests from within the adb shell?

Comment: You have described your intentions but seems to forget to ask the **question** (state a **problem**), with which you need our help.

Comment: "Is building cmake from source for the different android flavors my best option?" - "best option" for **what**? We won't recommend you whether it is worth to use CMake/CTest: this is mostly **subjective** choice, and Stack Overflow is not suited for *subjective questions*. If you decide to use CTest on the target machines for run tests, you obviously need it to be installed; if an installation from the sources is the only way for bring CTest/CMake to your target machines, then yes, you need to build CMake from sources.

Comment: "I can write a script to parse the existing files that ctest uses to find tests." - You may also replace `add_test` functionality in your CMake project, so it would generate tests in a format you want, so you won't be enforced to parse the format of tests for CTest. "... but I lose that nice aggregation that ctest gives." - It is what you need to choose. As I said above, subjective questions are not suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev editted it to be just a question.

Answer (score 0):

Generated a shell script from CMAKE that kept track of relative paths of all tests. Executed these tests from their paths on adb. No ctest aggregation though

Comment: Doesn't matter even if I can run ctest from within android adb. The CTestTestfile.cmake have absolute paths depending on where it was built which in this case would be the host machine.